# Sending push notification to android via FCM results in invalid-apns-credentials

Tags: go, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Trying to use official FCM package for Go to send push notification to Android user I get FCM error "invalid-apns-credentials"

I have a small code snippet in Go that sends push notification to Android user via FCM.

```
app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, nil,
    option.WithCredentialsJSON([]byte(credsJSON)),
)
client, err := app.Messaging(ctx) // err is nil here
_, err = client.Send(&messaging.Message{Token: "correct user device token", Android: &messaging.AndroidConfig{Data: map[string]string{"some":"data"}} // err is provided in description below
```

I use official FCM package for Go: firebase.google.com/go/messaging and `credsJSON` is a JSON string that was generated in FCM console for my project.
Despite sending push to Android user I get error `http error status: 401; reason: apns certificate or auth key was invalid; code: invalid-apns-credentials; details: Request is missing required authentication credential` which is obviously related to APNS (iOS) credentials. I would like to use this code to send android-only notifications, what am I missing?